# How to preinstall python packages with a custom colab runtime?

Tags: runtime, google-colaboratory

When using Google Colab, I usually need to install a bunch of libraries at the beginning

```
!pip install foo
!pip install bar
!pip install baz
```

Is it possible to create a custom runtime with all those libraries pre-isntalled, so that I can start coding right away?